# C# StreamWriter replaces characters of the value

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webrequest, streamwriter

I want to print a string expression from RequestStream in the request variable to the header variable in the code block below, but the incoming string changes the "+" characters in the expression to " ". I don't want '+' to be replaced by spaces, how can I solve this problem?

```
string headerVar = "W1wb948yHwyItOPOKC9P3+VPzQfVbP09yvY+X0"

        public void Sorgula(string variable)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("sample.com.tr?sID=" + variable);
            request.Headers.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
            request.CookieContainer = CookieJar;

            string header = "__HEADERVARIABLE=" + headerVar + "&OTHERHEADERVAR=" + otherVar;
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                streamWriter.Write(header);
            }
```

Sample :

Incoming Data      (headerVar)      : W1wb948yHwyItOPOKC9P3+VPzQfVbP09yvY+X0

What streamWriter writes : W1wb948yHwyItOPOKC9P3 VPzQfVbP09yvY X0

Comment: Sorry about my english!

Comment: *How can I solve this problem?* by replacing? or by not using `HttpWebRequest` or by not using application/x-www-form-urlencoded content type or it's not an actual problem as with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`  `'+'` would be decoded as `' '` on server side

Answer (score 0):

Try this maybe it solves your problem

```
   request.GetRequestStream()
     StreamReader streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(request.GetRequestStream());
     result = streamReader.ReadToEnd().Trim();
    header = result.Replace(+','with whatever character you want to replace');
```

Comment: thanks for reply but streamReader is bring the right data.

Comment: didn't get it what you wanted to say.